# Need to fill NaN with next values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe

[image]

My goal is to fill the Nan values in the 3rd and 4th column with
the non-Nan data in each column. Tried shift(-5) but didn't get it to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: `df.iloc[:5, [2, 3]] = df.iloc[5:, [2, 3]].to_numpy()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html):

```
df[['col3','col4']] = df[['col3','col4']].bfill()
```

**OR:**

```
df[['col3','col4']] = df[['col3','col4']].fillna(method='bfill')
```